# Python function definition works in console but not imported into ipython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am working on some helper functions for a project and I tend to use an ipython-notebook to help with dev. Anyways I am bumping into a strange occurrence where my function definition works from a python console, ipython console, and or if I paste the function definition into the ipython-notebook cell.

However, whenever I attempt to load the module from within the ipython-notebook and subsequently run said function, I get the following error. Also, everything works fine if I run the function from a console and import as usual or within an ipython console. I can import the function and it works.

To be clear, I can actually import the function into the ipython-notebook but actually running the function (after being imported) is giving the error below. Where as importing and running the same function the other ways (not within the ipython-notebook) does not produce the same error despite the code being exactly the same.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-f4cd5ccd5841> in <module>()
----> 1 fr(100, 1000, c_unit='micro', i_unit='micro')

TypeError: resonant_frequency() got an unexpected keyword argument 'c_unit'
```

Function definition

```
def resonant_frequency(capacitance, inductance, c_unit='base', i_unit='base'):
    ''' *** electronics.electronics.py
        * Useful for LC circuit work
        * Both the capacitance and inductance should be in there
          base measurment units. I.e. 100 uHz (micro-hertz) should 
          be 0.0001 Hz etc.

        * Resonant frequency equation is fr = 1 / (2Pi * squrt(capacitance * inductance))

        **********************************************************************************
        TODO make this function discriminate bewtween units so that a unit can be suffixed
        to the output, irregardless of what the inputs were (strings with unit suffixes in
        this case )
        **********************************************************************************
        Unit Table
        ----------

        |Text|Symbol|Factor|
        --------------------
        tera    T      1 000 000 000 000
        giga    G      1 000 000 000
        mega    M      1 000 000
        kilo    k      1 000
        hecto   h      1 00
        deca    da     10 # prob. will not ever use this but it's here
        (none)  (none) 1
        deci    d      0.1
        centi   c      0.01
        milli   m      0.001
        micro   µ      0.000 001 # the letter 'u' can be used here
        nano    n      0.000 000 001
        pico    p      0.000 000 000 001

        *******************************************

        **kwargs can be 'base' (automatic) or any of the prefix
        letters of above

        '''
    # convert capacitance and inductance from strings
    # to there respective base values
    units = {
        'T'   : 1000000000000,
        'G'   : 1000000000,
        'M'   : 1000000,
        'k'   : 1000,
        'h'   : 100,
        'da'  : 10,
        'base': 1,
        'd'   : .1,
        'c'   : .01,
        'm'   : .001,
        'u'   : .000001,
        'n'   : .000000001,
        'p'   : 0.000000000001
    }

    units1 = {
        'tera'   : 1000000000000,
        'giga'   : 1000000000,
        'mega'   : 1000000,
        'kilo'   : 1000,
        'hecta'  : 100,
        'deca'   : 10,
        'base'   : 1,
        'deci'   : 0.1,
        'centi'  : 0.01,
        'milli'  : 0.001,
        'micro'  : 0.000001,
        'nano'   : 0.000000001,
        'pico'   : 0.000000000001
    }

    # This should return frequency in Hz 
    if c_unit == 'base' and i_unit == 'base':
        return 1/((2*math.pi) * math.sqrt(float(capacitance) * float(inductance)))  

    elif c_unit in units and i_unit in units:
        return  1/((2*math.pi) * math.sqrt((float(capacitance)* units[c_unit])\
                * (float(inductance)*units[i_unit])))

    elif c_unit in units1 and i_unit in units1:
        return 1/((2*math.pi) * math.sqrt((float(capacitance)* units1[c_unit])\
                * (float(inductance)*units1[i_unit])))
```

Comment: Works fine for me (after importing `math`). `resonant_frequency(100, 1000, c_unit='micro', i_unit='micro')` returned `503.2921210448704`.

Comment: Did you load a previous version of the module in which the function did not have the `c_unit` keyword? If so, this could be a common issue: your module is not being reloaded on `import` and you either need to try `reload` or exit and restart IPython then import the updated module.

Comment: @Mr. F you are right. Initially I loaded a version that did not include the kwargs so that makes sense. I shut down the notebook and reloaded everything and now it works. Thank you.